# Irrlicht Engine: Window pops up and disappears instantly

Tags: irrlicht

I wanted to create a simple **IrrlichtDevice** with **IrrlichtEngine**, but when I start the application, the window just appears on the screen and then instantly disappears.

My **code** looks like following:

```
int main()
{
    IrrlichtDevice *device =
            createDevice( video::EDT_DIRECT3D9, dimension2d<u32>(640, 480), 16,
                    false, false, false, 0);
}
```

(code copied from the HelloWorld tutorial of the documentation)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
int main()
{
    IrrlichtDevice *device =
        createDevice( video::EDT_DIRECT3D9, dimension2d<u32>(640, 480), 16,
                false, false, false, 0);
    while( device->run() )
    {   device->getVideoDriver()->beginScene( true, true, video::SColor( 50, 50, 50, 50) );
        device->getVideoDriver()->endScene();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no looping system in place.  After you create the device the function immediately ends and everything is cleaned up.

bob2 has the correct answer,  I would suggest that you practice making simple c++ applications before diving in the deep end.